# What could I use to read and annotate pdf files on my tablet and have them sync to a reference management library?

Tags: android, pdf, file-synchronization, latex, annotation

I use [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) to manage my citation library with a WebDAV server to sync the files.  I would like be able to read and annotate the pdf files on my android tablet and have them sync back to the citation library.  Is there an application that would allow me to do this?

I understand it may not be possible with Zotero.  I have used [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) in the past but to have my large library sync between computers without paying a monthly fee I had to move the library and settings folder into my Dropbox.  This broke after a couple years so I went to Zotero.  When it was working, I could access the files from the Dropbox storage (every pdf was in the same directory), annotate them in the android Adobe PDF viewer, then Dropbox would update the file.  As a note, I did not use Mendeley's built in annotating tool as it only stored annotations in the software, not the pdf file (if I opened the file externally, it did not contain the annotations).

The difference is Mendeley would automatically rename the pdf files using the author name, publication title, and year.  In Zotero, the files do not get renamed and every file is in it's own folder, typically named something random (e.g. TUS5V6J2).  I am fine with switching to something else if it works well.  The important features I am looking for include

- Can sync library and >1 GB of pdf files between multiple computers with no monthly charge (one time charge would be alright)
- Useful desktop client
- Latex bibtex support
- Can annotate pdf files (annotations stored in the pdf, not the software) using android and the annotations will sync back to the desktop client

Thanks for any recommendations.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if it meets all your requirements, as I never used the sync part: Moon+ Reader Pro (the paid version) can annotate PDF pretty fine (this part I've used for proof-reading my books), and stores those annotations in the PDF file plus in its database. It can sync annotations/reading-pointers via Dropbox. Not sure how that works with the PDF file itself, as I've never used the sync. Unfortunately, no way to test this with the free version; but if you have use for a great eBook reader with good support, it might be worth the little amount of money.